# php pass multiple value from select list to sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a form has select list with multiple selecting option, what I need is to pass the multiple values to the sql statement in php.

example of the select list

```
<select name="site_name" size="10" multiple="multiple">
              <option selected="selected">Select ...</option>
              <option>UV</option>
              <option>US</option>
              <option>PI</option>
</select>
```

and this should pass UV or and US or and PI to the sql statement example

```
$sql = "SELECT Web_Page_Name FROM sites where Web_Page_Name =" $site_name[] ;
```

the previous is incorrect and I am looking for your help to know the correct sql statement to pass the multiple values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented it as below

1- I have changed the select list code to the below:

```
<select name="site_name[]" size="10" multiple="multiple">
              <option selected="selected">Select ...</option>
              <option>UV</option>
              <option>US</option>
              <option>PI</option>
</select>
```

2- sql statement in the 2nd page as below

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE Web_Page_Name IN ('"
. implode("', '", $_POST['site_name'])
. "')";
```

this is working good with me now

Comment: You did _not_ heed my advice. The code in this answer is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A1). You cannot simply call `implode()` directly on the `$_POST` variables. Each value must be encoded first.

Comment: hello, really I appreciate your help and caring to reply to me, I have tried the above and it working on most browsers without any problem, now I have the values inside sql statement an showing results.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct a sql statement using the [`IN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) keyword:

```
SELECT Web_Page_Name FROM sites where Web_Page_Name IN ('UV', 'US', 'PI');
```

As a sidenote, watch out for [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A1).

Comment: thanks for your reply, I want to use the in clause as an array from the selected values of the select list. they will not be fixed values.

Comment: @Pipo You'll have to build that string dynamically in PHP. There is no array parameter type. As I stated in the answer, be mindful of [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A1).

Comment: Thanks again, I'll check this source to have this